# How do I know which Eclipse M2E connectors I have installed?

Tags: eclipse, ide, maven-3, eclipse-wtp, m2e

I understand that the new M2E within Eclipse has pluggable connectors which help configure the Eclipse project based on what they see in the POM when the project is imported.

I also believe that (for the most part) these connectors are automatically installed when they are needed (on demand).  I've been using them with some success.  Recently I manually installed the M2E-WTP connector because I wanted to try it out.

I installed it via  `Eclipse->Preferences->Maven->Discovery` where I also found a bunch of additional connectors.  But the discovery window seems to only show you ones that you DON'T have installed.

But how do I know which ones I DO have installed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can see the list in Installed Software, go to Help->About Eclipse->Installation Details. In that list are the list of connectors:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this helps, but it seems like it should by on the Maven preferences.